# saving oTable rows (passing oTable rows to web service) datatables.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asmx, datatables

What is the quickest way to pass all rows of a datatables (oTable) to webservice?

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST",
....
data: <datatable rows>
```

and in C#
What data type?

```
[WebMethod]
public string Save470Form(<parameters>)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I passed is the json.stringify of .fnGetData();